# LLVM suitable parameters for the createBranchWeights()

Tags: llvm

We are trying to insrument branch instruction with the API SplitBlockAndInsertIfThenElse(). We noticed that the 3rd parameter of the API seems to be an "estimation" of the branch predication, which is generated by `createBranchWeights(param1, param2)`. However, we want to ask which parameter is suitable for the estimation, i.e., the parameter of the `createBranchWeights()`.

To the best of our knowledge, 64 and 4 are the llvm.expect's default values. Someone also uses `createBranchWeights(1, 1000)` to declare a rarely executed true branch. How the parameters affect the possibility of the branch? Which parameter is suitable?

Answer (score 1):

If your expect that one branch will be taken twice as often as the other, 2 and 1 are suitable. If three times as often, 3 and 1. If you have no idea, then you can skip setting this metadata. It is optional.